# Need Jquery plugin for color-picker

Tags: jquery, colors, picker

I need a small RGB color picker to integrate into my application.

I searched on google but could not find any suitable plugin that I am in need.

Also, I would be very grateful if someone suggest me a tutorial for creating a widget. I will need to learn in case any color-picker suggested are not suitable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [jscolor](http://jscolor.com), its super light weight, super compatible across all browsers i've heard of. Built using plain JS, but that doesn't hurt i guess. :)

Comment: You are awesome. That's what I want. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try this.. it's using the YUI Framework, but it'll get you what you want at no cost.

http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/examples/colorpicker/colorpicker-fromscript.html